# Correct way to structure this function

Tags: java, android

Well, I'm developing and app that communicates via bluetooth with another PCB. It consists on 3 seekbars that regulates the value of 3 parametres of the PCB.

The structure is this:

```
1. Send petition string for read the first value
2. Receive the first value
3. Send petition string for read the second value
4. Receive the second value
5. Send petition string for the third value
6. Receive the third value
```

I've done it, the way that a newbie like me can do the best. It works, but sometimes chrashes, so, I know that there are other ways to do it that can make it work perfect.

So, this is a request to someone generous that wants to have a look at the code and help me with it.

When we press the "read values" button, this is what it happens. It must be noticed that I use a runnable handler to wait 1 second between transmisions, to let the app read the answer to each request:

```
public void receiveValues() {       

    /**Petition string that is sent to the PCB to request the variable's value*/
    final String message_full1 = 2b e1 b4 e9 ff 1f b5;  //variable 1
    final String message_full2 = 2b e1 b8 e9 ff 1f b3;  //variable 2
    final String message_full3 = 2b e1 bc e9 ff 1f b1;  //variable 3
    final String message_full4 = 2b e0 bc f3 ff 1f 7c;  //save request
    final String message_full5 = 2b e0 be f3 ff 1f 7a;  //save status


    /*Send the first string to the PCB*/
    byte[] send1 = message_full1.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send1);


    /**Delay to wait until it receives the answer to the petition above*/
    read1_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**Read write confirmation after 1s = 1000ms*/
            String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";  //This string is what I receive as an answer via bluetooth

            /**We check that the received string is not null, to avoid program crash*/
            if (inpuRead != null) { //|| !inpuRead.equals("")) {

                /*If it nos null, then we call the next function*/
                int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);  //This function is declared below and extracts from the string , only the chars that we need.
                receive1 = splitInt;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Communication error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);


    /**Delay to wait to send de second petition string*/
    write2_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**write message 2 after 1s = 1000ms*/
            byte[] send2 = message_full2.getBytes();
            GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send2);
        }
    }, 2000);

    /**Delay to wait until it receives the answer to the second petition string*/
    read2_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**Read write confirmation after 1s = 1000ms*/
            String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";

            if (inpuRead != null) {
                int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);
                receive2 = splitInt;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Communication error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 3000);

    /**Delay to wait to send de third petition string*/
    write3_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**write message 3 after 1s = 1000ms*/
            byte[] send3 = message_full3.getBytes();
            GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send3);
        }
    }, 4000);

    /**Delay to wait until it receives the answer to the third petition string*/
    read3_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**Read write confirmation after 1s = 1000ms*/
            String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";

            if (inpuRead != null) {
                int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);
                receive3 = splitInt;

                /**Set loaded values on seekbars*/
                bar1.setProgress(receive1);
                bar2.setProgress(receive2);
                bar3.setProgress(receive3);

                /**Message indicating the end of the transmission*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Values loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Communication error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);

    /**This makes a save request on the pCB*/
    write4_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**write message 3 after 1s = 1000ms*/
            byte[] send4 = message_full4.getBytes();
            GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send4);
        }
    }, 6000);

    /**This request a save statos on the PCB*/
    write5_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**write message 3 after 1s = 1000ms*/
            byte[] send5 = message_full5.getBytes();
            GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send5);

            /**Reset out string buffer to zero*/
            GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        }
    }, 7000);
}


/**
 * FUNCTION THAT SPLITS THE RECEIVED STRING TO GET THE DESIRED VALUES
 */

private int splitReceivedString (String s) {  //For example, s = 2b 00 ff fe c7 80

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s," ");
    String one = tokens.nextToken();
    String two = tokens.nextToken();
    String three = tokens.nextToken();
    String four = tokens.nextToken();
    String five = tokens.nextToken();
    String six = tokens.nextToken();

    /**The next strings are whose got the seekbar's value*/  //f.e: "fffec780"
    received_hexValue = three + four + five + six;
    received_hexValue = received_hexValue.trim();


    /**Conversion from hex to int to set the seekbar's values*/
    int_value_receive = (int)Long.parseLong(received_hexValue, 16);
    int_value_receive = -200000 - int_value_receive;
    newIntValue = (int_value_receive * 100) / (200000 * (-1));

    return newIntValue;  //For this hex value, the int value to introduce in the seekbar is "60"
}
```

**UPDATED - PROBLEM ADDED**

The first thing that I want to do, but I don't know how is, when it enters on an `if`, if this is true, then it must continue executing the code, but if it isn't true, then it should get out of the function and stop executing the code. But the way I've done it, it continues executing.

The crash that I mean that I sometimes get is that sometimes, instead of getting the estructure this way:

```
1. Send petition string for read the first value
2. Receive the first value
3. Send petition string for read the second value
4. Receive the second value
...
```

It does something like:

```
1. Send petition string for read the first value
2. Send petition string for read the second value
3. Receive the first value
...
```

So here is where it crashes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code refactor.  

Comment: He does say it crashes sometimes, indicating a problem, but he doesn't state any specifics on it.

Comment: @Ruchira sorry but I don't know what do you mean with code refractor. I don't know where I have to ask this, just I'm asking for some help because I know that here is a lot of people that knows a lot about android and could fastly show me and example of how could be this done the right way

Comment: If you don't know what code refactoring is, look it up. Simply spoken, it means "cleaning up code" without changing behavior. This is not what SO is for and there are tons of books on that matter. Questions you ask on SO should relate to an actual, technical problem (i.e. that it crashes), but then you should provide proper information (exception, log output, ...)

Comment: @Ingo Bürk First of all, i know the structure isn't right because if one if isn't true and it goes to the else showing the "communication error" toast, i would like then the code to stop executing, but in this way it continues executing and I don't know how to do this. Other thing is that sometimes I don't get the received string at time and it sends 2 petition string at a time without getting first the received string

Comment: @Ingo Bürk I added the problem in the main question

Comment: Actually, you seem not never read anything from the connection. You simply set the value of the `inpuRead` variable in each task and don't touch the bluetooth connection. I suggest you think over what you want to do and instead of implementing the whole thing at once, go for implementing only the first message pair of the protocol. Once that works, go on. Start from scratch. You'll struggle forever with correcting this one. Resubmit you question on the code review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @allprog I put it his way for more clarity, but in real code I read that string from bluetooth

Comment: You shouldn't post those tasks in advance. Rewrite it to work on an event base. Handlers are exceptionally good for that. I like the way you approach the problem, but you should really move the question to codereview and add a not here about the new url.

Comment: @allprog code added in codereivew: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30866/correct-way-to-structure-this-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that 7 additional threads if you want that tasks to be executed bu turn. Just combine them in only one `Runnable` and things will be much easier.
I mean that all your `/**Delay to wait until...*/` comments are wrong, you're waiting 1 second after start of previous action. Thus, you just didn't finish "receive the first value" before "sending petition string for read the second value", because it took more time than 1 second.
**Example:**
Your code simplified:

```
private Handler read1_handler = new Handler();
private Handler write2_handler = new Handler();
private Handler read2_handler = new Handler();

public void receiveValues() {
  /**Delay to wait until it receives the answer to the petition above*/
    read1_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";  //This string is what I receive as an answer via bluetooth
            if (inpuRead != null) { //|| !inpuRead.equals("")) {
                int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);
                receive1 = splitInt;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Communication error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

    /**Delay to wait to send de second petition string*/
    write2_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] send2 = message_full2.getBytes();
            GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send2);
        }
    }, 2000);

    /**Delay to wait until it receives the answer to the second petition string*/
    read2_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";
            if (inpuRead != null) {
                int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);
                receive2 = splitInt;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Communication error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Code with proper execution order:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

//TODO: don't call functions read1, write2 etc, call it something like "readSomeValue" where "SomeValue" is what you're trying to read
private void read1() throws IOException {
    String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";  //This string is what I receive as an answer via bluetooth
    if (inpuRead != null) { //|| !inpuRead.equals("")) {
        int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);
        receive1 = splitInt;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        throw new IOException("Error in read1");
    }
}

private void write2() {
    byte[] send2 = message_full2.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send2);
}

private void read2() throws IOException {
    String inpuRead = "2b 00 ff fe c7 80";
    if (inpuRead != null) {
        int splitInt = splitReceivedString (inpuRead);
        receive2 = splitInt;
    }
    else {
        throw new IOException("Error in read2");
    }
}

public void receiveValues() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                read1();
                read2();
                read3();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Communication error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: And how is this done? I mean, what I know is that the code inside the runnable is executed after the time setted. So all the code inside this will be executed for example after 1 second... so, how it is done to executed the 7 tasks by turn inside only 1 runnable??

Comment: @masmic_87, I've edited my answer for more clarity. Why do you think that 1 second is the time that needed to complete previous action? What if you just copypaste all the code of your `Runnable`s to one of them and delete others, will it work right? (Of course, it will be much better if you'll create methods for each task and call it in that only runnable).

Comment: Well, I see from the computer where I've got connected the PCB all the strings sent and received, and watching I decided to set 1 second as the time to wait, but you are right that sometimes when it makes it wrong, sure that it is because as you say, it hasn't finished receiving the first value before start sending the second petition. For the other side, I understand what you are saying about setting all code inside only one runnable and create methods for each task, but I don't know how to do it. Could you edit you answer with a simple example of how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @SpongeBobFan! But how do you implement exceptions in that case? Sorry for asking so much, but I'm starting with this and I still have much to learn

Comment: @masmic_87, I've edited my answer. The code within `try` will stop executing when one of the methods throws an exception, then the `catch` block will be executed. The `catch` block is executed only when exception is thrown

Comment: @masmic_87, also I recommend you to read some book about Java, something like "Core Java". After that programming will be much easier for you

Comment: Yeah! i know it, but for this project i haven't had time and I have had to learn on the way... Just one more thing, I'm trying to understand the code. I see that you declare the functions and then you execute them inside the runnable, but I don't understand, because I see that you aren't setting a time to wait, so how is it working the runnable there?

Comment: @masmic_87, are you sure you need to wait 1 second? Maybe you need to wait for specific condition? In my answer I've proposed that after each task finished the next task is ready to go. You can add waiting by `Thread.sleep(1000);` or something like that if you need it, but waiting for magic time constant don't seems like a good idea

Comment: Yeah, maybe, but wich one? I receive random chars inside the string, so I can't compare to apply a condition, and the PCB doesn't send me any arrival confirmation... this is the reason why I tought about setting a specific time to wait... I know that isn't the best solution, but I can think of no idea of what I could use as a condition...

Comment: @masmic_87, What if you run the code without any waiting - will it work? If not, you can always add `Thread.sleep(1000);` after each method call, so your code will be like you wrote before asking the question, with only one difference - your task will be ordered right. What about protocol that you use to communicate with your PCB? How do you know that it is ready to send or receive data? You need some way to know that your transaction is over and the next one is ready to go, you need to implement this logic in your methods `read1()`, `write1()` etc. Waiting 1 second looks pointless anyway

Comment: I'll implement your method for sure, but without setting a time to wait as you say with the `Thread.sleep(1000);` I don't know if it will work. To initialize the communication, I send a string like this `2b c0 40` and the PCB then knows that the communication starts. Then, I send the first petition string, and it returns to me another string with the value that I need inside of it. So this could be the condition to wait for. The problem is that...

Comment: ...if I don't set a time to wait between The petition sent and the returned string, when it reads the bluetooth's input socket, chances are that it has not had time to receive the answer and gives me a null string...

Comment: I tried this way, but as I supposed, I've getted 2 petition strings sent at a time, then returned 2 strings at a time, etc... so I think that I would have to implement the sleep

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you could use cyclic barier, and depending on some magic delays is creazy.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

or maybe:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: Good answer, `java.util.concurrent` will surely help here, but I don't see a reason to complicate things such a way if you just want to complete some tasks by turn

Comment: Ahh just took quick look, so OP does not know that reads can be blocking operations, so code can execute after he finish receiving.